# how fix bug with Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

seconds after the App launches it crashes with this error in log:

```
07-27 11:27:33.261 27740-27740/com.msi.eluniversal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.msi.eluniversal, PID: 27740

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zziB(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzA(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3916)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1780)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
            07-27 11:27:39.151 27740-27881/com.msi.eluniversal E/GAv4: Successfully bound to service but never got onServiceConnected callback
            07-27 11:29:03.581 27740-27740/com.msi.eluniversal I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27740 SIG: 9
            07-27 11:29:03.831 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
            07-27 11:29:03.841 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
            07-27 11:29:03.851 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/ActivityThread: Switching default density from 640 to 480
            07-27 11:29:03.851 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
            07-27 11:29:03.861 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
            07-27 11:29:03.971 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
            07-27 11:29:03.981 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                              java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5979)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
        Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6384) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5979) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5919) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:198) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
            07-27 11:29:03.981 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
            07-27 11:29:04.031 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
            07-27 11:29:04.031 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
            07-27 11:29:04.081 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
            07-27 11:29:04.081 31553-31553/com.msi.eluniversal I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
            07-27 11:29:04.091 31553-31584/com.msi.eluniversal V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found
```

and I dont know how correct this error and i dont happen with Firebase or is GCM Google

I am using the next libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

and int he project gradle use this classpath:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: What version of google play services are you using. Could you post the gradle?

Comment: i am using 9.0.0 and 3.0.0, i am included in the post

Comment: My guess is that you are using the wrong library. 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
Should be used instead of 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

Comment: I used library com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0 for implemented login with Google, I don't know if it library the notifications used too same library

Comment: This type of error is usually associated with the version of Google Play services on the device. Could you try to update the device and you may want to move to 9.2.1 of the play-services libraries.

Comment: When updated Google Libraries to version 9.2.1, it's show the next error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0., because not use this library